# UIWebView zoom not working on ipad

Tags: html, ios, css, swift, uiwebview

I have a `UIWebView` and I show an image inside that `UIWebView`. On iPhone I can zoom the image but on an iPad I can not zoom it.

On the `UIWebView` I set `true` on the `scalesPageToFit` like the other answers says to be able to do zoom on the content.

This is the `html` I am using to show the images on the `UIWebView`:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width, maximum-scale=1.0'/>
        <style>
            img { 
                display: block; 
                margin: 0 auto; 
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body style='margin:0; padding:0; background-color: #A9A9A9;'>
        <img src='<the route of the image>' /> 
    </body>
</html>
```

What am I doing wrong or what do I have to do to can zoom it the image on an iPad?

Comment: You are setting maximum scale to 1... I guess if you modify the line it will work <meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width, maximum-scale=1.0'/>

Comment: @Neo ok I set to 10.0 and it works, thank you